# Displaying most common correlations in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three fields - userID, couponID, latest_couponID. For the last two fields, there could be pairs such as 1 & 3, 5 & 9, 10 & 3, just for example. I'm trying to find the most common pairs, and the amount of occurrences, and list them in order. How can I do that?

Comment: How many records are there? Why do you want to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select couponID, latest_couponID, count(*) as occurances from your_table group by couponID, latest_couponID ORDER BY occurances DESC;

Comment: How can I exclude results where `latest_couponID` = 0?

Comment: select couponID, latest_couponID, count(*) as occurances from your_table group by couponID, latest_couponID WHERE latest_couponID <> 0 ORDER BY occurances DESC;

Comment: The MySQL server is giving me a syntax error when I try to input the query with the exclusion.

Comment: SELECT couponID, latest_couponID, count(*) AS occurances FROM your_table WHERE latest_couponID <> 0 GROUP BY couponID, latest_couponID ORDER BY occurances DESC;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID, couponID, latest_couponID, count(*) AS freq
FROM table
GROUP BY couponID, latest_couponID
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

---

Formatting code